# How to properly switch between subviews of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am buidling an app in which I have a tableview in which my user can enter information on an employee. for practically all properties that can be added to my Employee object, I require a textfield, except for one: I need one cell in my tableview to contain a UISegmentedControl.

Now, this is how I originally wanted to do this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
        InfoCell *cell = (InfoCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"InfoCell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InfoCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (InfoCell *) [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

if (tableView == infoTable) {
    cell.title.text = employeeInfoArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.content.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.content.placeholder = @"Vul hier de gegevens in.";
    cell.contentSegmentedControl.hidden = YES;

    //determine textfield content
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.content.text = employee.userID;
        cell.contentSegmentedControl.hidden = YES;
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.content.text = employee.password;
        cell.contentSegmentedControl.hidden = YES;
    }else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        cell.content.text = employee.name;
        cell.contentSegmentedControl.hidden = YES;
    }else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
        NSMutableArray *companies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = 0; i < store.companies.count; i++) {
            Company *companyClass = store.companies[i];
            [companies addObject:companyClass.companyKey];
        }
        cell.contentSegmentedControl.hidden = NO;
        cell.contentSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:companies];
        cell.contentSegmentedControl.tag = 2222;
        [cell.contentSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        cell.content.hidden = YES;
    }
}
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

return cell;
```

}

Note that I have removed a lot of cells from this overview because you get the essence of the system out of this example with few cells as well: Every time a cell is loaded, it checks which index path it has, and what is needs to do, set the `textfield` (referred to as `content`) to hidden or the `contentSegmentedControl` to hidden.

The problem that I have is that when I normally scroll my tableview up and down, it shows everything properly. But when i start scrolling back and forward rapidly, I get my contentSegmentedControll in all kinds of cells that it is not meant to be in.

I am extremely curious why this occurs and how I could solve this. My own suggestion would be to add multiple custom tableviewcells, but I have no idea how to do that properly.

**To put things short:**
How do I prevent my uisegmentedcontrol, which is meant to be in only one of my `tableViewCells`, from popping up in random cells when scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you hide the segmentedControl in every case that you have not pasted? If not, try this:

```
if (indexPath.row == 3) {
    cell.segmentedControl.hidden = YES;
} else {
    cell.segmentedControl.hidden = NO;
}
```

And remove the code that references segmentedControl everywhere else

Answer (score 0):

It's probably happening a delay when loading the cell that contains the `UISegmentedControl`, because every time you scroll, the cell have to populate the `companies` array before displaying the cell.

To fix this, consider reducing the loading frequency of the `companies` array, for example, storing its values in a `property`, and calling `tableView:reloadData` or even better `tableView:reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation` if the content of the array `companies` changes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Note that the companies array is not populating the tableview. the companies array is populating the segmented control with segments. It is meant to allow my user to select a company to which a specific employee belongs. I don't think this issue is datasource related. instead, I think when scrolling fast iOS fails to accurately populate cells with different settings. how can I prevent this?